# How to set up Selenium WebDriver (Python) with DigitalOcean floating IP

Tags: python, selenium, digital-ocean

With a droplet on DigitalOcean, is it possible to use a floating ip when starting a Selenium WebDriver in Python?

This is the code being used to start the webdriver.  What do I need to do to make it use a floating IP?

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(my_driver_location, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
browser.get(start_page)
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: Errors?  I'm not sure what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(my_driver_location,
chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

with:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
browser = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://192.168.99.100:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        )
```

192.168.99.100 is your floating IP, 
4444 is port of your floating IP